# What is the name of these palms?

Tags: identification, plant-recommendations, planting, palm, ornamental-plant

I have a question about the name of those plants and I would also like to know how to care for them.

[image: Imagen 1][image: imagen2]

Comment: This is not enough info to answer.  The top one looks like...Sago Palm...the scale looks like an ant's perspective.  The bottom picture could be a Mexican Fan or a Wind palm that recently got beat up or eaten.  What is the connection and what is your question concerning these two plants?

Comment: Totally agree with [stormy](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/3351/stormy), upper one is [Sago Palm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycas_revoluta) or *Cycas revoluta*. Second image is not clear enough, please add a better picture.

Comment: Hello, José! Please ask separate questions if you have two species, otherwise the answers might be partial and difficult to follow. I didn't vote to close your question (yet) because I'm waiting for your edit. If you need help, please let us know.